# Fixed point algorithm

Tags: equation-solving

I have a function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{3} (2-e^x + x^2), [a,b]=[0,1]$
I start with an initial value of $.5$
What I am trying to do is write a short program that takes my initial $P_0 = 0.5$, plug it into the function to output $P_1$, put $P_1$ back into the function to output $P_2$, and take that value, put it back into the function to get $P_3$, etc. I want it to stop when $|P_n - P_{n-1}| \leq 0.0001$

I have written this, but I don't get any output from it:

```
 f[x_] := (1/3)*(2 - Exp[x] + x^2);
 a = 0.5;
 Do[{c = f[a]
      If[Abs[c - a] > 0.001, a = c
         Print[c]]
      If[Abs[c - a] <= 0.001, Print["The solution is " c]]
    }, {i, 1, 10}];
```

If you are so kind to give me advice, take into account my only programming experience was FORTRAN from 22 years ago, so I am quite lost!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this do what you want? `With[{eps = 0.0001},
 FixedPoint[Function[{x}, (1/3)*(2 - Exp[x] + x^2)], .5,
  SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < eps &)]
 ]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FtgIY.png)

Comment: @Nasser: Is there a way to get that snippet to print the individual steps as it iterates?

Comment: @Moo, yes, but need to replace `FixedPoint` with `FixedPointList`, like this `With[{eps = 0.0001}, 
 FixedPointList[Function[{x}, (1/3)*(2 - Exp[x] + x^2)], .5, 
  SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < eps &)]]` and this gives `{0.5, 0.200426, 0.272749, 0.253607, 0.25855, 0.257266, 0.257599, 
0.257512}`

Comment: Excellent - should have figured that out - thanks!

Comment: That definitely does it! Thank you. @Nasser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun:

```
f[x_] := (1/3)*(2 - Exp[x] + x^2);
it[n_] := 
 Flatten[{#1, {#2[[1]], #2[[1]]}, #2} & @@@ 
   Partition[NestList[{#[[2]], f[#[[2]]]} &, {0.5, f[0.5]}, n], 2, 1],
   1]
fp = {t, t} /. FindRoot[f[t] == t, {t, 0.2}];
vis[n_] := 
 Show[Plot[{f[t], t}, {t, 0, 1}, 
   Epilog -> {Purple, PointSize[0.04], Point[fp], PointSize[0.02], 
     Green, Point[fp], Black, Text[fp, fp, {-1/2, 4}]}], 
  ListPlot[it[n], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, .3}}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"Iteration ", n , ":(", it[n][[-1, -1]], ")\n", 
     Style["error: ", Red], Abs[it[n][[-1, 1]] - fp[[1]]]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The literal way to do what you are requesting is:

```
Last /@ NestWhileList[{#[[2]], (2 - Exp[#[[1]]] + #[[1]]^2)/3}&, {0.,0.5}, Abs[Subtract @@ #] > 10^-4 &]
```

It isn't necessarily the fastest or best way, but it is precisely how you are envisioning the recursion.  The output is the list of successive iterates $P_0, P_1, \ldots, P_n$.  The built-in functions `FixedPoint` and `FixedPointList` are more efficient, but `NestWhile` and `NestWhileList` are more flexible.

---

The broad reason why your code fails to run as you expect is because you are attempting to use *Mathematica* as if it were a procedural programming language, when it is actually a functional programming language.  The way *Mathematica* handles expressions, conditional statements, and assignment is different than languages like Fortran or C.

Comment: That code yields an error: `Subtract::argr: Subtract called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected.`

Comment: @corey979 There was a missing ampersand after the `10^-4`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one simple way to approach this iteration:

```
f[x_] := (1/3)*(2 - Exp[x] + x^2);
NestList[f, 0.5, 20]

{0.5, 0.200426, 0.272749, 0.253607, 0.25855, 0.257266, 0.257599, 0.257512, 0.257535, 0.257529, 0.257531, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753, 0.25753}
```

You can see that it settles to a constant value after about 11 or 12 iterations.

Answer (score 5):

Like Nasser's comment

```
NestWhileList[1/3 (2 - Exp[#] + #^2) &, 0.5, Abs[#1 - #2] > 0.0001 &, 2] //N

{0.5, 0.200426, 0.272749, 0.253607, 0.25855, 0.257266, 0.257599, 0.257512}
```