# Recursive function called for specified accuracy

Tags: recursion

I have an implicit function

```
g=f[x,y,z,g]
```

which I want to call recursively, called initially with `g=0`. I have this working for a specified number of recursive calls `rec`.

```
h[x_, y_, z_, rec_] := Piecewise[{{f[x, y, z, 0], 
 rec == 0}}, f[x, y, z, h[x, y, z, rec-1];
```

Is there a neat way build a function keeps increasing `rec` until the change in `h` falls below a certain threshold?

thanks,

Comment: Maybe FixedPoint would help.

Comment: Perhaps [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) would be relevant

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I think I have my own answer, thanks to [more reading](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125993/fixed-point-algorithm/125995)...

```
h[x_, y_, z_] := Last[NestWhileList[f[x, y, z, #] &, 0, Abs[#1 - #2]/#2 > 0.01&, 2]]
```

finds the answer with enough recursion for 1% accuracy.